# How to insert objects in a vector efficiently and correctly

Tags: c++, reference

Suppose I want to declare a vector of objects. I can do it this way -

```
vector<mynode> nodes;
```

But if the size of the mynode is large, this would be bad. So I think of doing it this way -

```
vector<mynode*> nodes;
```

But the above declaration has an obvious problem that I'm storing addresses and it's not safe at all. For instance, if i add objects in a foor loop -

```
vector<mynode*> nodes;
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    mynode mn;
    nodes.push_back(&mn);
}
```

This will lead to errors as I can never guarantee if the contents of the pointer are actually ok.

So, I decide to use this declaration -

```
vector<mynode&> nodes;
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    mynode mn;
    nodes.push_back(mn);
}
```

is this ok? safe? It gives a compilation with the first line itself. Please suggest some efficient way of storing the objects in a vector. thanks a lot.

Comment: Nope, storing by references is exactly as bad as storing by pointers.  If you do frequent inserts and that's slowing your program, consider using another data structure (`deque`?), or `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<mynode>>`.  Also: Your question name does not match the question itself.

Comment: Don't worry about optimizing the vector unless your profiling shows it to be an actual problem. The first form `vector<mynode>` is the best.

Comment: @MooingDuck, storing references isn't even possible, since references can't be reassigned.

Comment: Do you *need* a `vector`? Maybe a `list<mynode>` would be more appropriate.

Comment: @GregHewgill Vector, list or whatever container, if he wants to avoid copying it, he needs pointers. If he doesn't want to worry about validity of these objects, he needs smart pointers.

Comment: @stanwise: I was thinking about insert/delete performance, rather than the copying effort required to get the object into the container in the first place. But whatever, the OP hasn't given enough details for an accurate answer.

Answer (score 3):

> I can do it this way -
>
> ```
> vector<mynode> nodes;
> ```
>
> But if the size of the mynode is large, this would be bad.

No, it would not. You need to store the objects anyway. If you are worried about *copying* large objects, you have some solutions:

1. Use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<my_node>>` (or another smart pointer), which automatically releases objects on destruction. This is the best solution if `my_node` is polymorphic.
2. Use `std::vector<my_node>` and use the `emplace_back` function to construct objects in place (beware if you're using visual studio 2010, this function does not do what it is supposed to do).
3. Still use `std::vector<my_node>` and use `push_back` with a rvalue reference, as in

   `v.push_back(std::move(some_node));`

   to move already constructed objects.

Anyway, a good rule of thumb is to have the copy constructor/assignment deleted (or private) for most non-lightweight objects. Containers are still functional (provided, again, that you use C++11) and your concerns are moot.

Comment: Add a missing space in: `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<my_node> >`

Answer (score 1):

Using references gives is essentially the same as using pointers (it's just that you don't need to dereference them in code).
If you want to automatically ensure that the objects inserted to vector don't get deleted without copying them, you should use smart pointers from boost or c++11.

```
vector< smart_ptr<mynode> > nodes;
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    smart_ptr<mynode> mn = new mynode();
    nodes.push_back(mn);
}
```

Comment: To create a vector with 10 nodes, what about `std::vector<mynode> nodes(10);`

Comment: @BoPersson - sure, but I just wanted to show example of usage on the same case that OP presented.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see pointer being so bad here. It's not void or something. Inserting reference as in your example saves a reference to a temporary object located on a stack an this will go out of scope...

Comment: Using raw pointers here *is* bad, since it is not exception safe (the difficulty of C++ mainly comes from exception safety concerns): the memory is leaked if an exception propagates upstream without the objects being released.